# CSS Calendar Display

Tags: asp.net, javascript, css, vb.net

I created my own custom date picker consisting of an ASP TextBox, Button, and Calendar complete with CSS styles, javascript code, and event handling vb code.

I want to use this date picker multiple times on my form.  I know the wrong way to do this would be to copy all the code and just adjust each name accordingly.

How can I put those controls, styles, and code into a single entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a user control (.ascx) out of your controls and use it as many times as you need on your form.

More on user controls:

ASP.NET User Controls Overview
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx

Walkthrough: Creating Reusable Elements with ASP.NET User Controls
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3457w616.aspx